Can I eat this bacon without cooking?
I bought the bacon in the picture. They couldn't tell me how it was prepared. But they strongly advised that I need to fry it in order to eat it.
I was wondering, is this just a cultural thing (southern Mexico)? Or should I actually refrain from eating this bacon raw (with some bread)?

